# Как из конструктора абстрактного класса использовать переопределенное поле из дочернего класса (typescript)

Tags: javascript, классы, typescript, конструктор

Мне нужно создать иерархию из одного абстрактного класса и нескольких унаследованных от него классов. У каждого класса есть свое уникальное имя (поле `NAME`), которое используется для инициализации большого количества параметров при создании экземпляра (для простоты заменил просто на метод `printName`). Эта логика одинакова для всех классов, поэтому мне нужно вынести ее в конструктор абстрактного класса. А при создании нового конкретного класса должно быть достаточно реализовать одно простое поле или несложный метод (новые классы могут создаваться другими разработчиками, нужно  минимизировать их настройку).

```
abstract class AClass
{
    protected abstract NAME:string;

    constructor() {
        this.printName();
    }

    private printName = () => {
        console.log(this.NAME);
    }
}

class ImpClassOne extends AClass
{
    protected NAME: string = 'name1';
}

class ImpClassTwo extends AClass
{
    protected NAME: string = 'name2';
}

const one = new ImpClassOne();
// Ожидаю в консоли 'name1'

const two = new ImpClassTwo();
// Ожидаю в консоли 'name2'
// В обоих случаях получаю 'undefined'
```

Но новые имена не подтягиваются. Сначала отрабатывает конструктор абстрактного класса, который использует только свой экземпляр поля `NAME` (а оно undefined), а только потом конструктор нового класса (который уже видит правильное имя, но поздно, потому что настройка была проведена в суперклассе).

И вот вопрос, как в суперклассе брать переопределенное имя из дочернего класса? Или какую тогда структуру для вызовов выбрать, чтобы все заработало? Главное - при создании нового класса должно быть минимум настроек. В других языках я такой проблемы не помню, вроде суперкласс сразу всё подтягивал. Думал о паттерне "шаблонный метод", но из конструктора вызвать абстрактный метод тоже нельзя. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какой target компиляции?

Comment: @Qwertiy ES5, но могу новее, если нужно для решения этой проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал статические поля (но в ES5 до них хуже добираться): [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1&useDefineForClassFields=true#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkIAOUA9hDvDgCYKTAQCWsC9tqUeAcgEEAsgFEAXE2isAdgHMA3IWKlYlaZCgBXeJSgAKAJQFlpUhAAWrMADoKMiH2ABbHHuk4A7tYjAosnBDWgqIGiqYAvkqmdgBuLHh20g7OrtIpEhoyskZEpqaq6pTIONbIlLJuKaEmCJGRhChoGADClsj0AIwIOAAeNNL0GNhgeLmkFNS0NIzMbBzBIggAvAgA5GkuHauK9Y3oCK2s7QBM3X04A0O4xtFUNHQzPnMIC8trGzjH24S7apAIPTe7g8BzanUMigK-wAnkDPKCjvRjhDCEA)

```
abstract class Base {
    protected static declare NAME: string;

    constructor() {
        this.printName(new.target.NAME);
    }

    private printName(name: string) {
        console.log(name);
    }
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    protected static NAME = 'name1';
}

class Child2 extends Base {
    protected static NAME = 'name2';
}

const x = new Child1();
const y = new Child2();
```

> А есть способ, при котором можно и потом обращаться к этому полю? То есть из конструктора через `new.target.NAME`, а потом, не из конструктора, просто через `this.NAME`? Ведь оно может понадобиться и после отработки конструктора.

Ну сохранить в поле: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&ssl=24&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkIAOUA9hDvDgCYKTAQCWsC9tqUeAcgEEAsgFEAXE2isAdgHMA3MVIVqtGo0GiJkKDIWElJWJWk6ArvEpQAFAEoCh0iQgALVmAB0mkQgC8CaRwAdw8IYChZHAgvYRFFJydXdw8KGQg+YABbHDt40gBfAydUgDcWPFTpdKyc+yIE0mNTSmQcD2RKWWskz29bPJJCwsIUNAwAYTdkegBGBBwADxppegxsMDx65SoaOkZmNg5vPwQAcmkamdPFYdH0BEnWaYAmeaWcFbXcB2KdtQZJCx2Ahjv5zjVntdCLcTJAEAsToEgg8prNciNYYgAJ6I4Iop70Z7ooA)

```
abstract class Base {
    protected static declare NAME: string;
    protected NAME: string;

    constructor() {
        this.NAME = new.target.NAME;
        this.printName();
    }

    private printName() {
        console.log(this.NAME);
    }
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    protected static NAME = 'name1';
}

class Child2 extends Base {
    protected static NAME = 'name2';
}

const x = new Child1();
const y = new Child2();
```

Comment: А есть способ, при котором можно и потом обращаться к этому полю? То есть из конструктора через `new.target.NAME`, а потом, не из конструктора, просто через `this.NAME`? Ведь оно может понадобиться и после отработки конструктора.

Comment: @MrShnaider, дополнил.

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает. Чтобы поле не забыли реализовать в дочернем классе, присвоил `NAME` по умолчанию `null` и в конструкторе кидаю ошибку, если оно `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через геттер или метод, но мне это не нравится: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkIAOUA9hDvDgCYKiQzwJQ7D2UB2yAnggByAQQCyAUQBcCFgEseAc0LFSsXiwCu8SlAAUASgKrSpCAAs5YAHQUFEIcAC2OQyYQBfFabsA3YDTkUPaOLobGpqbqPGCUyDjWyJSKehZW1qKSBu5eXoQoaBgAwpbI9ACMCDgAHjQ89BjYYHhEPlQ0dIyKOIiZEuH47D2aUDwIAOQ8zjjl456EeQXoCCVyZQBMVbU49Y24EaQU1LQ0XT3C4v1GgxwQI2OT0+tzuSrRkAjVCAC8CDw4AHcVqUKoYANz5DSIQS-f5A1YbcGEIA)

```
abstract class Base {
    protected abstract readonly NAME: string

    constructor() {
        this.printName()
    }

    private printName() {
        console.log(this.NAME)
    }
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    protected get NAME() { return 'name1' }
}

class Child2 extends Base {
    protected get NAME() { return 'name2' }
}

const x = new Child1();
const y = new Child2();
```

Comment: А из-за того, что в классе используется не стрелочная функция, не будет проблем с контекстом?

Comment: @MrShnaider, ну разберись, как оно устроено и подумай.